# How to set a background image in a Java Applet?

Tags: java, image, background, applet

How would I set a background-image in a Java Applet?

I have an animated .gif image, and I want it to be the background in my Java Applet. How would I do this?

Comment: I think that could be a solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7293587/background-images-in-java-applets

Comment: Thanks for that. Can you post it as an answer so I can accept?

Comment: What's with the votedown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Following could be a solution:

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.IOException.*;

public class BackgroundApplet extends Applet {
     Image backGround;

     public void init() {

          // set the size of the applet to the size of the background image.
          // Resizing the applet may cause distortion of the image.
          setSize(300, 300);

          // Set the image name to the background you want. Assumes the image 
          // is in the same directory as the class file is
          backGround = getImage(getCodeBase(), "save.GIF");
          BackGroundPanel bgp = new BackGroundPanel();
          bgp.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
          bgp.setBackGroundImage(backGround);

          // Add the components you want in the Applet to the Panel
          bgp.add(new Button("Button 1"));
          bgp.add(new TextField("isn't this cool?"));
          bgp.add(new Button("Useless Button 2"));

          // set the layout of the applet to Border Layout
          setLayout(new BorderLayout());

          // now adding the panel, adds to the center
          // (by default in Border Layout) of the applet
          add(bgp);
     }
}

class BackGroundPanel extends Panel {
     Image backGround;

     BackGroundPanel() {
          super();
     }

     public void paint(Graphics g) {

          // get the size of this panel (which is the size of the applet),
          // and draw the image
          g.drawImage(getBackGroundImage(), 0, 0,
              (int)getBounds().getWidth(), (int)getBounds().getHeight(), this);
     }

     public void setBackGroundImage(Image backGround) {
          this.backGround = backGround;    
     }

     private Image getBackGroundImage() {
          return backGround;    
     }
}
```

You'll find further Information here: [Background Images in Java Applets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7293587/background-images-in-java-applets)

Answer (score 2):

Here is many possible answers.

Here is the one of them.

Suppose that you have a Class BcgImageApplet which extends Applet:
In order to set background image to your applet you should use this:

```
public class BcgImageApplet extends Applet  {

    Image I;

    //Irelevant code avoided.

    public void init() {
        I=getImage(getCodeBase(),”your_picture.jpg”);
    }

    //Irelevant code avoided.

}
```

In short - in your init() method you have to set image to your Applet.

Comment: No problem, I just posted if you have more solutions / clarifications.